# Quora scraper fails with TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape my own posts from Quora. I tried to scrape it using the command
`quora-scraper users -l ['Kaleab-Woldemariam']` which gave stack trace:

```
C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\scrapy_projects>quora-scraper users -l [Kaleab-Woldemariam]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\quora-scraper.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 555, in main
    users(keywords_list,save_path)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 330, in users
    browser= connectchrome()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 42, in connectchrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\scrapy_projects>sys.path.insert(0,r'(C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
'sys.path.insert' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\scrapy_projects>quora-scraper users -l [Kaleab-Woldemariam]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\quora-scraper.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 555, in main
    users(keywords_list,save_path)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 330, in users
    browser= connectchrome()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 42, in connectchrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\scrapy_projects>quora-scraper users -l ['Kaleab-Woldemariam']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\quora-scraper.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 555, in main
    users(keywords_list,save_path)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 330, in users
    browser= connectchrome()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\quora_scraper\scraper.py", line 42, in connectchrome
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1119, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "c:\python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 530, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added absolute path to webdriver.exe to driver_path in Scraper.py and webdriver.py and it worked.